# EF with WCF: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, entity-framework-4.1

When I retrieve all orders and their OrderDetails from ASP.NET MVC through WCF it throws error. till service it works fine, only when the call reaches out of service in this case MVC, it throws error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

1. I am not using lazy loading
2. I want to use same POCO class, don't want separate create DataContract in WCF.

My code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        var allOrders = service.GetAllOrders();
        service.Abort();
        return View();
    }       
}

// WCF Service Method
public List<Order> GetAllOrders()
{
    List<Order> orders = null;
    using (NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
        orders = context.Set<Order>().Include("Order_Details").AsEnumerable().ToList();
    }

    return orders;
}

public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.Order_Details = new HashSet<Order_Detail>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Order_Detail> Order_Details { get; set; }
  } 

public class Order_Detail
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public short Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a navigation property called Order on your Order_Detail POCO? If so, can you remove it for a moment and try again? I think the Json serializer used by WCF is unable to deal with cyclic references.

Comment: no i dont have order property in order_detail entity.   updated above codeblock. please refer

Comment: Can you please post your NorthwindEntities configuration?  Does Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled equals true?

Comment: Alex,

by default proxycreationenabed was true, after disabling it works fine.

thanks

        public List<Order> GetAllOrders()
        {
            List<Order> orders = null;

            using (NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                orders = context.Set<Order>().Include("Order_Details").AsEnumerable().ToList();
                context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

            }

            return orders;
        }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks to Alex,

it works after disabling ProxyCreationEnabled.

```
    public List<Order> GetAllOrders()
    {
        List<Order> orders = null;

        using (NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            orders = context.Set<Order>().Include("Order_Details").AsEnumerable().ToList();
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

        }

        return orders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a timeout issue. At a guess, try setting the executionTimeout property in the httpRuntime element, as per the following -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Comment: given maximum timeout duration. but still it throws.  db doesn't have huge data. ef data loading completes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The result message may bo too large to send back to the client according to the default limits.

You can use WCF trace log to find out what went wrong. See [this](http://litemedia.info/wcf-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly) link.